# I get a error when I try install auto-complete in emacs on mac

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm newbie in emacs. I got an error when I try install auto-complete...I install it from https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete

when I make it, I got an error like this:

```
Loading subst-jis...
Loading subst-ksc...
Loading subst-big5...
Loading subst-gb2312...
Loading subst-jis...
Loading subst-ksc...
Loading subst-big5...
Loading subst-gb2312...
cask install
make: cask: No such file or directory
make: *** [.cask/22.1.1/elpa] Error 1
```

what am I doing wrong??...thanks!!!

Comment: I'm one of those anti-homebrew and anti-macports folks (for a variety of reasons), and I prefer to build my own or use a prebuilt binary from:  http://emacsformacosx.com/ ,which also offers nightly builds of the experimental developer snapshot:  http://emacsformacosx.com/builds  While the nightly builds offer many OSX specific bug fixes not available in the last stable public release, it may contain some surprises that are not found in that last stable public release.

Answer (score 1):

You got error because [cask](https://github.com/cask/cask) is not installed.
But you need not to install Cask if you don't develop auto-complete.

Steps for installing auto-complete are here.

1. Install newer Emacs by [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) or [macports](https://www.macports.org/).

Emacs(/usr/bin/emacs) which is installed on MacOSX is very old. Recent packages does not work on it.

2. Add following setting to your configuration file(`~/.emacs.d/init.el`).

   ```
   (require 'package)
   (package-initialize)
   (add-to-list'package-archives '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/") t)
   ```
3. Restart Emacs
4. `M-x package-refresh-contents`
5. `M-x package-install` then you type `auto-complete`

See Also

- http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/emacs_package_system.html